# Angular 8 Custom Validator never returns errors

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have created a form group with a Custom Validator to compare dtDebut and dtFin (dtFin must be higher than dtDebut) :

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.pensionForm = this.fb.group({
  dtDebut: ['', Validators.required],
  dtFin: ['', [this.dateValidator]],
  montant: ['', Validators.required],
  nivInv: ['', Validators.required],
});


get f() {
    return this.pensionForm.controls;
}

onSubmit2() {
    this.submitted = true;
    console.log(this.f.dtFin);
    if (this.pensionForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
}


dateValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
        if (control.value < this.f.dtDebut.value) {
            return { dateValidator: true };
        }
    return null;
    }; 
}
```

But the dtFin Form Control never returns me an error, the form Control is always "Valid". And Moreover, the attribute f is not known ... How can I catch error ?

Comment: I suggest you either try seeing what exactly happens in your filter by using the javascript console in your browser and debugging there, or you provide a minimal working example using stack blitz that we can use to understand the problem a bit better. 
Your code is relatively incomplete and the description doesn't help too much in understanding exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to compare two form controls you will have to set a validator for the form group. This can be done as follows.

```
dateValidator(group: FormGroup) {
    if(group.get('dtFin').value < group.get('dtDebut').value) {
        return { dateValidator: true };
    } else {
    return null; 
    }
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.pensionForm = this.fb.group({
        dtDebut: ['', Validators.required],
        dtFin: ['', Validators.required],
        montant: ['', Validators.required],
        nivInv: ['', Validators.required],
    }, {validators: [dateValidator]});
 }
```

Comment: Grpup base validator is the best case her m you are right , 

Answer (score 0):

try to below way

```
export function dateValidator(dtFin: FormControl,dtDebut : FormControl ) {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    if (dtFin.value < dtDebut.value) {
      return { dateValidator: true };
    }else{
        return null;
     }
   }
}



  ngOnInit(){
  this.pensionForm = this.fb.group({
  dtDebut: ['', Validators.required],
  dtFin: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, dateValidator])],
  montant: ['', Validators.required],
  nivInv: ['', Validators.required],
 });
}
```